# Difficulty accessing json file with d3 and flask

Tags: python, json, d3.js, flask

I am using Flask as a web framework, and I am trying to implement the first example from the book *Getting Started with D3*, by Mike Dewar. I have a Python script named `run.py` and two directories, `templates/` and `static/`, containing `index.html` and [service_status.json](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920025429/mikedewar-getting_started_with_d3-bdfc34e/visualisations/data/service_status.json), respectively. Unfortunately, my code is not rendering the data at all, nor is it producing any glaring errors.

This is what I have in `run.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=="__main__":
    port = 5000
    app.debug = True
    app.run( port=port )
```

This is what I have in `templates/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <META CHARSET="utf-8">
  <SCRIPT SRC="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></SCRIPT>
  <SCRIPT>
    function draw(data) {
        "use strict";
        d3.select("body")
        .append("ul")
        .selectAll("li")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("li")
        .text( function(d){
            return d.name + ": " + d.status;
            }
        );
    }
  </SCRIPT>
  <TITLE>MTA Data</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <H1>MTA Availability Data</H1>
  <SCRIPT>
    d3.json("{{ url_for( 'static', filename='service_status.json') }}",draw); // <---- BIG PROBLEM
  </SCRIPT>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I am using Windows 7, Google Chrome, and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the JSON file is not going to change, then you should put it in the `static` directory and use

```
from flask import url_for
url_for('static', filename='service_status.json')
```

For this to work, also change the path in the JavaScript to `'/static/service_status.json'`

Comment: I put the *url_for(..)* line after the *app* declaration, and I got the following error: **"Attempted to generate a URL with the application context being pushed. This has to be executed."**

Do I need to do something with *app.test_request_context()*? Or am I missing something else that is really obvious? (I just picked up flask and web-related things in general last week.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. `url_for(...` should be after `app.run()`, inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` conditional

Comment: I moved the `url_for(..)` line after `app.run()`. I still get the application context error, but I don't get the 404 error anymore.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I found my error, I had used `selectall()` instead of `selectAll()`, but putting the json file in the `static/` directory was also an essential thing that I totally missed.

Answer (score 5):

Static files like your json document, are by default served from a different directory from the templates - [by default 'static'](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files)

You dont need to use the url_for call in your view, you can use it in your template:

```
d3.json("{{ url_for('static', filename='service_status.json') }}",draw);
```

So to summarise: 1) Move your json document in to the static folder (a folder called static along side your templates folder, by default), and 2) use the url_for call in your template to get the correct URI for your json document.

If you want to use a folder other than static, you can change that by passing [`static_folder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-object) to the Flask object contructor

Comment: I have the json file in the static directory, and I put the `url_for(..)` call in the template, but the data is still not being rendered.

I am getting these messages:
    ..."GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    ..."GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
    ..."GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    ..."GET /static/service_status.json HTTP/1.1" 304 -
    ..."GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting a 304 status code as you mentioned in earlier comments. I see that your JSON has the following date/time:

```
"Date": [
    "12/15/2011"
], 
"Time": [
    " 7:35AM"
],
```

I am not 100% sure but this might help:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#if-modified-since

Basically, it says that

"This request header is used with GET method to make it conditional: if the requested document has not changed since the time specified in this field the document will not be sent, but instead a Not Modified 304 reply.
Format of this field is the same as for Date:"

So, may be you can check the timestamp on the JSON and probably just do a fresh save ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I created the json file this morning. Also, the 304 status code has been (magically) cleared up by implementing the advice of @DazWorrall.

Comment: ok. I thought that you responded to @DazWorrall that you are still getting "..."GET /static/service_status.json HTTP/1.1" 304 ". If not, then np.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my problem statement a while after I posted it, but now some of the comments are dated.